# Style <select> corners for webkit

Tags: webkit, css

What I am trying to do is to round corners of a `<select>` using "border-radius". Strangely, webkit browsers show white background overflowing borders of the `<select>`.

**Update**
Here's the screenshot and my code:

[image]

HTML:

```
<select class="rounded_select">
   <option>rounded_select</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.rounded_select {
     border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
     border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
     border-right: 2px solid #eee;
     border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Are there any ideas how to fix it?

**Update**: It is preferrable to save the button image on the right of the select.

Comment: please show some code for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

`-webkit-appearance:none` might do the trick.

**EDIT**: Yep that appears to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/dbxjB/

Comment: `-webkit-appearance:none` helps to get rid of overflows, but it cuts out the button image on the right of the select as well. Sorry for not mentioning this fact in my question.

Comment: Are you seeing what you want in other browsers? I'm not sure what the end result is that you want. You are right that this approach remove the button image, but you can add your own: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit

Answer (score 0):

Setting `background-color` for the `select` seems to do the trick.

Edit: Does not. Setting border to 1px did it. As well as 2px dashed for example. Glitchy.